# Constraint on an array with same values group together

Tags: constraints, system-verilog

I have two rand arrays: `pointer` and `value`. Whatever values in the `pointer` should also come in `value` with same number of times. For eg: if `pointer[i]` == 2, then `value` should have a value 2 which occur two times and should be after 1. 
Expected result is shown below.

[image]

Sample code:

```
class ABC;
  rand int unsigned pointer[$];
  rand int unsigned value[20];

  int count;

  constraint c_mode {
    pointer.size() == count;
    solve pointer before value;

    //========  Pointer constraints =========//
    // To avoid duplicates
    unique {pointer};

    foreach(pointer[i]) {
      // Make sure pointer is inside 1 to 4
      pointer[i] inside {[1:4]};

      // Make sure in increasing order
      if (i>0)
        pointer[i] > pointer[i-1];
    }


    //========  Value constraints =========//

    //Make sure Pointer = 2 has to come two times in value, but this is not working as expected
    foreach(pointer[i]) {
      value.sum with (int'(item == pointer[i])) == pointer[i];
    }

    // Ensure it will be in increasing order but not making sure that pointers are not grouping together
    // For eg: if pointer = 2, then 2 has to come two times together and after 1 in the array order. This is not met with the below constraint
    foreach(value[i]) {
      foreach(value[j]) {
        ((i>j) && (value[i] inside pointer) && (value[j] inside pointer)) -> value[i] >= value[j];
      }

    }

  }

   function new(int num);
     count = num;
   endfunction

endclass

module tb;
  initial begin
    int unsigned index;
    ABC abc = new(4);
    abc.randomize();
    $display("-----------------");
    $display("Pointer = %p", abc.pointer);
    $display("Value = %p", abc.value);
    $display("-----------------");

  end
endmodule
```

Comment: It should be good if there is another way for ` value.sum with (int'(item == pointer[i])) == pointer[i];` .. because value.sum is affecting the performance

Comment: Is the pointer array random at all? What can the values be outside the pointer specified numbers?

Comment: As of now I have kept the pointer values to be inside 1 to 4.

Comment: @dave_59 Pointer value can be 1, 3, 5 .. But in value we should get count(1) = 1, count(3) = 3, count(5) = 5.. same as the above table

Answer (score 1):

I would implement this using a couple of helper arrays:

```
class pointers_and_values;

  rand int unsigned pointers[];
  rand int unsigned values[];

  local rand int unsigned values_dictated_by_pointers[][];
  local rand int unsigned filler_values[][];

  // ...

endclass
```

The `values_dictated_by_pointers` array will contain the groups of values that your pointers mandate. The other array will contain the dummy values that come between these groups. So, the `values` array will contain `filler_values[0]`, `values_dictated_by_pointers[0]`, `filler_values[1]`, `values_dictated_by_pointers[1]`, etc.

Computing the values mandated by the pointers is easy:

```
  constraint compute_values_dicated_by_pointers {
    values_dictated_by_pointers.size() == pointers.size();

    foreach (pointers[i]) {
      values_dictated_by_pointers[i].size() == pointers[i];
      foreach (values_dictated_by_pointers[i,j])
        values_dictated_by_pointers[i][j] == pointers[i];
    } 
  }
```

You need as many groups as you need pointers. In each group you have as many elements as the pointer value for that group. Also, each element of a group has the same value as the group's pointer value.

For the filler values you didn't mention what they should look like. I interpreted your problem description to say that the values in the pointers array should only come in the patters described above. This means that they are not allowed as filler values.  Depending on whether you want to allow filler values before the first value, you will need either as many filler groups as you have pointers or one extra. In the following code I allowed filler values before the "real" values:

```
  constraint compute_filler_values {
    filler_values.size() == pointers.size() + 1;

    foreach (filler_values[i, j])
      !(filler_values[i][j] inside { pointers });
  }
```

You'll also need to constrain the size of each of the filler value groups, otherwise the solver will leave them as 0. Here you can change the constraints to match your requirements. I chose to always insert filler values and to never insert more than 3 filler values.

```
  constraint max_number_of_filler_values {
    foreach (filler_values[i]) {
      filler_values[i].size() > 0;
      filler_values[i].size() <= 3;
    }
  }
```

For the real `values` array, you can compute its value in `post_randomize()` by interleaving the other two arrays:

```
  function void post_randomize();
    values = filler_values[0];
    foreach (pointers[i])
      values = { values, values_dictated_by_pointers[i], filler_values[i] };
  endfunction
```

If you need to be able to constrain `values` as well, then you'll have to implement this interleaving operation using constraints. I'm not going to show this, as this is probably pretty complicated in itself and warrants an own question.

Be aware that the code above might not work on all EDA tools, because of spotty support for random multi-dimensional arrays. I only got this to work on Aldec Riviera Pro on [EDA Playground](https://www.edaplayground.com/).

Comment: The code for `post_randomize` is not the most efficient, as it does a lot of array creations. You can simplify it by creating the values array once and assigning its elements from the other two arrays.

Comment: Is there any way to move the concatenation of values to be a part of constraints rather than doing in post randomization ?

Comment: Moreover the size of values = 20. That is not reflected in the code

Comment: @Salim I said in the post that the concatenation stuff is a question of its own. With "question" I mean an own StackOverflow question.

Comment: @Salim Your constraint that you want as most 20 values just means you need to constrain the number of elements in the two arrays for real and filler values.